# Save multiple attached files in mail to different locations based on extension using Outlook VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a process whereby a user completes an Excel form and 'submits' it via Email.

I wrote VBA code such that an email is created and sent with two attachments, an xlsm and xml file.

When the 'submission' is received by Email a rule runs a script to save this data. I want to save one attachment to one folder and one attachment to another. This means that I have all my XML files in one place to pick up later and I've retained the original Xlsm files.

```vb
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat

dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "mm-dd H-mm-ss")
saveFolder = "c:\Automated Quality Procedures\Excel Forms\Recieved Files\"
saveFolder2 = "c:\Automated Quality Procedures\Excel Forms\Recieved Files\XML Files\"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

    If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xlsm") Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName

    ElseIf InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".XML") Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder2 & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName & ".XML"

    End If

    Set objAtt = Nothing

Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately this code saves both files in "Savefolder" and nothing in "SaveFolder1".

Comment: Are you sure the extension is really XML and not xml (lowercase)?

Comment: the extension is .xml, although this shouldnt make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

InStr function is case sensitive, so if the extension is "xml" (lowercase), `InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".XML")` will return false for upper case.

Either use lower case  ( `InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, ".xml")`), or tell InsStr to use case-insensitive comparison: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: H,, I did try that but it doesnt seem to make a difference, I changed it to this: